# ORA-00933 in ODI procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-data-integrator

I'm mapping two table in ODI and I have a problem.

i've mapped the source table to the target table (called `DM_BUSINESS` with the columns `BUSINESS_ID, NAME, ADDRESS`). After that I've created a procedure with:

```
UPDATE dm_business SET name = CONCAT(name, CONCAT(' ', address)) WHERE name IN (SELECT name FROM dm_business GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT (business_id)>1);
```

When I run this query myself, with SQLDeveloper, I have no problem and it all works fine: it adds the address of the business to its name, when there are more than one business with the same name.
When I run the procedure with this task, it gives me error `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`. I have choosen "Oracle" as target technology. What do I do wrong?

Can you help me? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the semicolon to run it as an SQL statement or wrap your UPDATE with BEGIN..END to run it as a PL/SQL block:

```
BEGIN
   UPDATE ... ;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you, removing the semicolon makes it work. I'm surprised I didn't try it before.